# how to do step-by-step code in unity 'void Update{}'?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm going to make track follower.
and here's my track in unity
[Track image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whL3f.png)

I want to operate codes 1 ~ 10 at step by step in unity C# script method void Update{},
but I can't find how to make it.
I make rotation code using with trigonometric systems, Sin and Cos.

```
Rigidbody rigidbody;
public GameObject ball;
Vector3 P1 = new Vector3(-5, 1.5f, 25);
public float theta;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    ball.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, P1, 0.05f); // 1st move

    if(theta <210)         // 2nd rotation with trigonometic equations
    {
        theta += 1;
        ball.transform.position = Rot(theta);
    }
}

Vector3 Rot(float theta)   // rotation by trigonometric equations
{

    Vector3 P2;
    P2.x = (3 * Mathf.Cos(theta * Mathf.PI / 180) - 3 * Mathf.Sin(theta * Mathf.PI / 180)) -8;
    P2.y = 1.5f;
    P2.z = (3 * Mathf.Sin(theta * Mathf.PI / 180) + 3 * Mathf.Cos(theta * Mathf.PI / 180)) + 22 ;
    return P2;

}
```

if I play that code, the ball just warp to position P1 and immediately start rotation
 how can i use that?

and can't use keyboard or something else input handler, only use by codes

Answer (score 0):

To debug in unity you will need to use visual studio debug tool. Click on the play button "Connect with Unity" and play on the unity side. You will of course need to put a debug point where you need it.

Note: Your game will be stuck during the Update debug, if you can and you need to see update in the game view just execute the code that you need to debug in a coroutine.
If you just need to know the value of a variable you should be able to debug it without any problem even in the update.